# How to bring label over edit control

Tags: forms, delphi, controls

I'm trying to set up a TEdit that will be used for research, so, it would be great to have a label displaying "current" / "count" over it, as observed by pressing CTRL + F in Google Chrome:
[image]

It seems that the TLabel control's always placed behind the TEdit control. 
[image]

I also tried label1.BringToFront (Both at designtime and runtime), but it had no effect. Is there a way to place a label over an edit control?

Comment: That's what the `TStaticText` control could do. But better paint the text directly into the control. And don't forget to clip the edit box input rectangle by the `EM_SETMARGINS` message.

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong in my view. This needs to be one custom control.

Comment: `TLabel` inherits from `TGraphicControl` which cannot be shown on top of windowed controls. Like others have said you really are better of creating your own custom control for this.

Comment: Thanks to all, as suggested, I will define a custom control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TLabel` inherits from `TGraphicControl` which cannot be shown on top of windowed controls, no matter how many times you try to use `BringToFront` it's just not going to happen.

However, you can use a container control such as a `TPanel` that can be used to contain your `TEdit` and `TLabel` controls, see this image as an example:

[image]

That is a quick and dirty way, it's simply a `TPanel` containing a `TEdit` and `TLabel` as child controls

The preferred way however is to create your own control which would give you full flexibility. Often trying to piece together multiple VCL controls to appear and function how you want is not usually ideal, and so by doing it the custom way gives you more freedom and possibilities.